# RegEx Validations

Tags: regex

I am new to Reg Expressions.  How can I check if a textbox can only hold Y,y,N,n values, Textbox 2 can only have string "abc" or "cba" What will be the ValidationExpression?
I will really appreciate help.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first example:

```
/[YyNn]/
```

Your other example:

```
/(abc|cba)/
```

I recommend reading about regular expressions here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html

Answer (score 1):

`Y|y|N|n` for Textbox 1
`(abc)|(cba)` for Textbox 2

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to regular expressions, may I recommend this?
http://code.google.com/p/kiki-re/

It's a regular expressions tester, you write your regex and some text to text it. It's really nice to learn about regexes and to test them too ;).